# Advantages of using a RDBMS

Tags: reference-request, databases, filesystems

Apologies if this isn't the correct forum but I thought it would be too academic for the DBA forum. In my work I'm looking to research some of the benefits of using an RDBMS product over traditional files (text, XMLs JSON what have you).

I'm not planning to cover the advantages over Big Data / NoSQL but that would be a bonus.

Is there an academic paper(s) that I can start my research from?

To narrow it down I would say the advantages around indexing, validating relationships and database views are what I would like to concentrate on but anything will be highly appreciate.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Have you tried looking in some textbooks on databases?

Comment: I think stackoverflow is the right place to ask this. This is rather a question of practical considerations (what kind of data you're storing? what's the access pattern like? are there simultaneous reads/writes? what guarantees you need about your data? transactions? ..etc.), software engineering more than computer science. I would look for advice from SEs, not research papers. I tried searching for your question on stackoverflow (I found many results like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900324/why-use-sql-database). Hope this helps!